# Issue with generating multiple excel files in php

Tags: php, mysql, excel, cakephp, batch-processing

I've to generate invoices in multiple excel files (1 excel file for each invoice). There could be around 70 excel files that will be generated. The process will 1st fetch the data from database and then write it to the excel files. After generating the files (I'm storing them on my server), all of them needs to be zipped and then have to be sent as email to a user.

Generating excel files, zipping them and email is easy. My my concern is, I've to generate many files and it would definitely take some time. What's the best way to do this? I Just want to tell the users that we will email you after some time. What should I use? threading ? or something like that. I'm using php. I was reading about php `Gearman extension`, but I'm confused if this could help me?

Comment: The best way to do it is a backend process, whether using a job server such as gearman or rabbitmq to queue the requests, or something as simple as a cron job

Comment: Would it be good if I use gearman on the same server? thanks

Comment: If the server can handle the workload, then there's no reason why not: Gearman workers run in separate threads started from the command line.... I've run both webserver and gearman server and workers on the same server in test/dev environments without issue, though for a large system you might want to farm it out to a separate server or servers